# Noun for rule to strengthen a preexisting one

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I was wondering if there is a noun built off the word strengh the same way we find the word corrective as built off the word correct.
The context would be a term for second rule or law which is created specifically to add strength to a preexisting one.

Comment: Examples of what you're talking about would be helpful. Do you have any laws in mind?

Comment: The process is usually referred to as [a] tightening of existing laws.

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence that shows us how you'd like to use this noun?

Comment: @edwin, "*tightening*" suggests to me *refinement*; making the law more precise, or perhaps plugging loopholes. You could also *strengthen* a law by increasing its ambit, say, or the punishment imposed for breaking it.

Comment: I was sent here from Mi Yodea a site about Judaism. I'm trying to find a term for a specific type of law created by Rabbis whose sole intent is to strengthen the observance of a preexisting biblical law. A positive action to help the observance of the biblical. As apposed to a negation of an action as a corrective safeguard.

Comment: @Smiley: Create an example, please: a sentence which includes a blank where you'd like this *noun* to go (please note: "*corrective*" is not a noun, it's an adjective; similarly "*strengthening*" is an adjective. If the new law is intended to provide additional, positive sanctions for adhering to to an existing law, you might call that new law an "*incentive*" [noun] or "*incentivizing*" [adjective]).

Comment: @Dan 'Corrective' is certainly a noun (as well as an adjective). 'Strengthening', on the noun - verb continuum, can be used as one as here: 'The strengthening of the defences took place in 1345'.

Comment: @Edwin, I should have said "*in your statement [corrective safeguard]*, corrective is an adjective".

Comment: @Dan Yes, I'm surprised: 'strengthen the law' is most common according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strengthen+the+law%2Ctighten+the+law%2Ctighten+up+the+law%2Creinforce+the+law&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrengthen%20the%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctighten%20the%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctighten%20up%20the%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creinforce%20the%20law%3B%2Cc0), though 'reinforce the law', as well as 'tighten [up] the law' are used too.

Comment: @Edwin, I think you should add an answer suggesting "reinforcement". I think that nails it.

Comment: @Dan Read Smiley's first comment!

Comment: The term you require is probably so domain-specific that you'll be advised to return to a site dealing specifically with Judaic practices!

Comment: *supportive, strengthening, reinforcing, augmentative, supplementary, consolidatory,* etc., etc. Unless there's a specific domain-specific (legal, or ecclesiastical) term, this is probably Too Broad.

Comment: _beefing up_ is possibly as far as you can get from the legal and religious domains.

Comment: bolster. in the sense of supporting or adding strength it's not a noun, in the sense of a support it is a noun.

Comment: So the problem is I need a noun I can reffer to. I can mention 'that specific law', but I can't reffer to 'that specific beefing up, or bolster'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent built straight off "strength", but "reinforcement" comes close, since "force" and "strength" bring one another to mind.

A 'strengthening' of a law, like a 'correction' of an order, replaces the law and fixes it.  A 'reinforcement' of a law, like a 'corrective (measure)' on an order would lie beside it, leaving the original in force, and filling gaps or shaping its interpretation.

Comment: Of course there's an "equivalent". OP's *corrective = promoting correctness* is mirrored by *strengthening = promoting strength*.

Comment: But 'strengthening' is seldom a noun of the appropriate type.  it would be 'equivalent' to 'correction', not 'corrective'.  I do not think there is a parallel form that is not just casting to a noun, but referring directly to the process involved by casting first to an adjective and then again from the adjective to the noun.

Comment: OP is obviously a bit fuzzy about "parts of speech", since adjectival *correct* corresponds to *strong*, not the abstract noun *strength*. But just because *strengthening* can also be used as a "gerund" noun doesn't affect the fact that it's also an ordinary verb - and an adjective in common collocations such as [strengthening exercises](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22strengthening+exercises%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: But since both forms of 'strengthening' are identical, there is not one that is more like 'corrective' than 'correction'.

Comment: You miss my point. Whether OP cited *corrective* or *correction* as "built off" *correct* doesn't alter the fact that *correct* is an adjective, whereas *strength* is an abstract noun (which I suppose you could say is "built off" *strong*). And undeniably the semantic relationship between adjectival *corrective* and *correct* is the same as that between *strengthening* and *strong*. Which is as much as to say the first sentence in your answer is simply incorrect, since *strengthen[ing]* clearly fits the bill.

Comment: OK, but you miss the subtlety of the question.  If you go to your doctor and he gives you a prescription, and it bothers you, and you go back, and he sends you home with a different perscription, that is a correction.  BUT, if that correction takes the form of addition to address a side-effect of the original, and no other changes, only THEN is it a CORRECTIVE.  They do not want something as straightforward as 'strengthening;'.  That would be the equivalent of the less subtle term.

Comment: Reinforce! Brilliant. Thank you and everyone who weighed in over here.